# how to call only blocktopmenu module in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

can anyone tell me how to call only `blocktopmenu` module in prestashop...if i use `displayTop` hook it calls various other modules along with it..but i only want to call `blocktopmenu`..is it possible to create an object of `Blocktopmenu` class and access the `hookDisplayTop()` of that class..so that i can avoid other modules...i tried but its not working

when i try to implement this

[Call Module in tpl file in prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459117/call-module-in-tpl-file-in-prestashop)

it shows "This module cannot be transplanted to this hook."

Comment: i already create an extra module to transplant blocktopmenu..but not working

Answer (score 1):

When you call Hook::exec() you can specify a module ID in the 3rd parameter.
It would be something like that:

Hook::exec('displayTop', null, Module::getModuleIdByName('blocktopmenu'));

Regards,

Comment: What are the errors?
I tried with the following code in index.php and it worked:

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
Controller::getController('IndexController')->init();
echo Hook::exec('displayTop', null, Module::getModuleIdByName('blocktopmenu'));
die;

Comment: try it in FrontController.php

Comment: It should be noted that this only works when module is already hooked. For example in this case module "blocktopmenu" must be already bound to "displayTop" hook (in admin panel). Otherwise it just returns empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Never touch the FrontController.

You have to create a new hook, then attach your module to this hook. 
After that, you can call Hook::exec('your_hook').